# git workflow with a complication

Tags: git, version-control, merge, workflow

I work on a small team developing a product that deals with a lot of expensive data. Because of the cost associated with this data, it is not possible to fully test code locally. Instead, we have a production server that our clients see, and a staging server that we use for testing. Likewise, we have a branch that matches production (we're using "master"), and a branch that matches staging (called "staging").

I've done a good bit of searching on the topic of git workflows, but they all seem to assume that the team churns away on some development branch (maybe directly, or maybe using feature branches that are merged in). And when everything in that branch is good to go, it's merged into the production branch (maybe through a "release" branch first) and the process repeats. This is the way the popular [Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) works.

The problem is that our "staging" branch (which is the closest thing we have to the "develop" branch in the aforementioned Successful Git Branching Model) regularly has code that is in various stages of completeness. Because we cannot fully test our code locally, incomplete or broken code often ends up in the staging branch so it can actually be tested against the ridiculous amount of data our app deals with on the staging server. We cannot wait for everything in the staging branch to be completely done, tested, and working before we release stuff to production.

So what's the best way to handle this? So far, I've experimented with:

1. Feature branches based on the "staging" branch that can be merged into staging and then cherry-picked to master when ready.
2. Feature branches that are merged into staging for testing, and merged into master when ready. Not sure if it's best to base these branches off staging or master...

Either way, I've been getting merge conflicts where there really aren't conflicts because the history is getting all screwy. That's kind of annoying. There must be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Ugghhh in any case, you run the risk of commits on staging interacting with each other in a way that won't happen in production because you aren't moving all the commits on staging to master together, but you've been testing them on staging together.

I think git makes this hard because it's not a good idea :-/ What about using feature flipping so that certain functionality is only active in the staging environment but the code can be pushed to production at any time? This will require a change in the way your team thinks about doing development-- rather than changing existing code, sometimes you'll have to add a parallel path through the app that uses new functions that will eventually replace the existing functions wholesale.